# Insert Password Encryption on Steganography Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, steganography

I am writing a Matlab steganography program.

Here is the procedure for the embedding process:

1. Insert image as cover image (.bmp)
2. Insert message file as message (.txt/manual input from user)
3. Insert password encryption as stego key on edit text box

For the extracting process:

1. Choose image as stego image (.bmp)
2. Insert password decryption as stego key, same as from Embedding Process
3. Extract message and show time elapsed process

The problem is from embedding process (step 3) and extracting process (step 2)

I've created a function for embedding and extracting a message (without password), that works properly. But I am confused about how to insert password as steganography key and verify it in the extracting process?

If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Many thanks!

Comment: It seems that you have already asked the same question.....
I dont know much about how steganography is done but I think the password will be embedded to the image same way the message was done....(probably at a given position)
I highly suggest you to read about steganography deeply first

Comment: I've read some literature that steganography as usual only embedd message and didn't using password encryption. Firstly I've think about same way to embedd password just like message, but how to compare when  the user goes to extract process @adil ?

Comment: I think, this password you refer is the key to reset MATLAB's PN generator to that state "key".You use this key to embed your message and the same key to extract it also after distort your image. This distortion is used to check how robust your algorithm is in possible attacks and extract ROC curves for benchmarking.I hope that I had understand what you said and help you with this comment.

Comment: So Mr. @Darkmoor is there any function that I can use for this statement?

Comment: I do not think so it is a function. Let me give you an example tha I hope it will help you.